# Not seeing any speedup using openmp

Tags: c, openmp

I am very new in openmp and am trying to understand its constructs..

Here is a simple code I wrote... (square of the number)..

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20000
#define NUM_THREADS 50
int main(){

    int id;
    int output[SIZE];
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    //{
        //id = omp_get_thread_num();

        for (int i=0; i<SIZE;i++){
            id = omp_get_thread_num();
            //printf("current thread :%d of %d threads\n", id, omp_get_num_threads());
            output[i] = i*i;
        }
    //}
    double end = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("time elapsed: %f for %d threads\n", end-start, NUM_THREADS);
}
```

Now, changing number of threads should decrease the time.. but actually it is increasing the time?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: To start learning, remove the `omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);` line (unless you have 50 cores on your CPU). Also, there just might not be enough work per thread to justify the overhead of launching the threads.

Comment: Try looking into the [schedule()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5aw0hdf.aspx) method. If you use dynamic scheduling it will automatically decide for you the optimum thread configuration for your program given the hardware available.

Comment: @AviGinsburg But even one thread is faster than 2 is faster than 3 threads.. I have 16 core machine..Whats the simplest example which I can go thru to understand parallel for construct?

Comment: Your work per thread is tiny (one multiplication * size / threads). Add more work to each iteration to try and see where it improves. Alternatively, you can increase `SIZE`, but in any case, such a simple example might be better optimized by the compiler when not using OMP than when using it. That might also be a source of performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to your choice of problem to inspect.   Lets look at your parallel loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<SIZE;i++){
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    output[i] = i*i;
}
```

You have specified 50 threads and stated you have 16 cores.

The serial case ignores the OMP directive and can perform aggressive optimization of the loop.  Each element `i` is `i*i`, a simple multiplication dependent on nothing but the loop index.  `id` can be optimized out completely.  This probably gets completely vectorized and if your processor is modern it can probably do 4 multiplies in a single instruction (SIMD) meaning for `size=2000`, you are looking at 500 SIMD multiplications (with no data fetch overhead and a cache friendly store).  This is going to be *very* fast.

Alternatively, lets look at the parallel version.  You are initializing 50 threads -- expensive!.  You are introducing many context switches as even if you have processor affinity, you have oversubscribed your cores.  Each of the 50 threads is going to run 40 iterations of your loop.  If you are lucky the compiler unrolled the loop a bit so it could instead do 10 iterations of a SIMD multiply.  The multiplies, whether SIMD or not, are still going to be fast.  What you end up with is the same amount of real work, so each processor has 1/16th of the work but the overhead of 50 threads being created and destroyed creates more work than the parallel gain.  This is a good example of something that doesn't benefit from parallelization.

---

The first thing you want to do is limit your number of threads to your actual cores.  You are not going to gain anything by adding needless context switches to your execution time.  More threads than cores is generally not going to make it go faster.

The second thing you want to do is to do something more complicated in your loop, and do it many times (google for examples, there are many).  When constructing your work loop you will also want to keep cache performance in mind, as badly constructed loops don't speedup well.

When you change your work to be more complex than the thread overhead, embarassingly parallel and great cache performance you can start to see a real benefit to OpenMP.  The last thing you'll want to do is benchmark your loop from serial to 16 threads.  e.g.:

[image]